# ¿Llamar una función varias veces en laravel para consumir una API?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, laravel-blade

estoy empezando en Laravel y estoy llamando una API, he aplicado paginador e iniciaría en 0 y traería de a 3 elementos, para la próxima vuelta iniciaría en 3 y nuevamente trae 3 para seguir así. Hasta ahí funciona si doy clic a un botón insertar en mi archivo Blade voy haciéndolo manual, ahora si mi duda. ¿Cómo podría ejecutar esa función de insertar cada x tiempo?

Comment: Laravel ofrece una herramienta llamada `scheduling`, lo cual te permite ejecutar lo que le pongas cada X tiempo. Otra manera con la que podrías hacer esto, es creando una tarea programada en tu servidor para que llame a una ruta de tu aplicación, y tu ahí gestionar lo que desees

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Gracias Maidagan, no conocía esta herramienta, la probaré